# Jenkins job unstable after adding Ansible playbook command

Tags: docker, jenkins, ansible, cicd, dockerhub

I successfully connected my Jenkins server to my Ansible server/control node and it built a stable and successful job after I made a change to my github too. But when I actually created an ansible playbook to create and tag a docker image and then push to dockerhub. I added 'ansible-playbook regapp.yml' to the Ansible configuration in my Jenkins server and it gives this error:

[image]

For context, this is the playbook I created:

```
- hosts: ansible

  tasks:
    - name: create docker image
      command: docker build -t regapp:v2 .
      args:
        chdir: /opt/docker

    - name: create tag to push image onto dockerhub
      command: docker tag regapp:v2 codestein/regapp:v2

    - name: push docker image
      command: docker push codestein/regapp:v2
```

Things I've tried:

- Resetting my docker container. I did rm -rf /var/lib/docker and then `systemctl restart docker`
- Changed webapp/target/webapp.var on Jenkins config to '**/*war' and vice versa.
- Gave ansadmin:ansadmin control/access of /opt/docker directory

Not sure how else to fix the issue. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: 1. What is the Pipeline code? 2. What is the relevant verbose output from Ansible?

Comment: Hey @MattSchuchard I didn't deploy the pipeline as a code. I'm doing it semi-manually (still learning, hence my questions) just to understand the concepts first before automating fully. Also, when I enter ```ansible all -a uptime``` it shows that ansible successfully connects to both the Jenkins and Docker servers. Btw, thanks for taking time to reply to my question, thought no one was gonna respond.